# Problema con algoritmo en PSEINT Error 303

Tags: pseint

Saludos a todos quienes entraron para ver el tema, comento que estoy usando la última version de PSEINT.

El problema trata de lo siguiente, al ejecutar el código me indica error 303, en este apartado valores[0,0]<-0;

Desconozco si la sintaxis debe cambiar para lograr obtener lo mismo, ya que en alguna version anterior ese código corría sin problema.

Estoy recién comenzando y seria de mucha utilidad aprender de qué manera solucionar este problema.

El código es:

```
SubProceso salir()
Limpiar Pantalla;
Escribir "----------------------";
Escribir "----Ok Adios!!----";
Escribir "----------------------";
FinSubProceso
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
SubProceso errorOpcion()
Limpiar Pantalla;
Escribir "-----------------------------------------------";
Escribir "----Error en la Opcion Del Menu----";
Escribir "-----------------------------------------------";
Esperar 1 Segundos;
FinSubProceso
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
Proceso Ejercicio_03_Subrutinas
Definir op, valores Como Entero;
Definir datos Como Cadena;
Dimension valores[5 , 3], datos[5 , 1];
op<-0; valores[0,0]<-0;

Repetir
    Limpiar Pantalla
    Escribir " ----------------";
    Escribir " --- Menu ---";
    Escribir " ----------------";
    Escribir " 1.Agregar Libros";
    Escribir " 2.Listar Libros";
    Escribir " 3.Estadistica";
    Escribir " 4.Buscar Libros";
    Escribir " 5.Salir";
    Escribir " Digite una Opcion";
    Leer op;
    segun op Hacer
        1:
        2:
        3:
        4:
        5: salir();
        De Otro Modo: errorOpcion();
    FinSegun
Hasta Que op=5;
FinProceso
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te fijaste de buscar ese error en la documentacion de pseint? en google? al parecer ese valor esta fuera de los rangos del array. estas seguro que el array arranca en 0, y no en 1?

Answer (score 0):

Primero es Definir y no declarar

Segundo, verifica que estés usando un perfil que configure los arreglos para que sean en base 1, aquí está trabajando con arreglos en base 1 y los más seguro que estés en un perfil donde los arreglos sean en base 0